# R for loop not updating dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop

So I have this code that does a for loop but doesn't actually update my dataframe after the first run. If I do two runs without the for loop it works just fine. I'm probably overlooking something obvious but really don't see it.

Here is the code:

```
#preparation
data <- c("MARRIED", "DIVORCED", "MARRIED", "SEPARATED", "DIVORCED", "NEVER MARRIED", "DIVORCED", "DIVORCED", "NEVER MARRIED", "MARRIED", "MARRIED", "MARRIED", "SEPARATED", "DIVORCED", "NEVER MARRIED", "NEVER MARRIED", "DIVORCED", "DIVORCED", "MARRIED")
observed <- c(table(data))
n <- sum(observed)
k <- length(observed)
expProb =rep(1/k, k)
pObs = dmultinom(sort(observed, decreasing=TRUE), size=n, expProb)

counts <- seq(0, n, by = 1)
kCounts <- matrix(,nrow=n+1, ncol=k)
for (i in 1:k){
  kCounts[,i] <- counts
}

all_perm <- merge(kCounts[,1], as.data.frame(kCounts[,2]),all=TRUE)
all_perm <- all_perm[rowSums(all_perm) <= n,]

#THE FOR LOOP THAT DOESN'T WORK
for (i in 3:k){
  print(i)
  all_perm <- merge(all_perm, as.data.frame(kCounts[,i]),all=TRUE)
  all_perm <- all_perm[rowSums(all_perm) <= n,]
  print(dim(all_perm))
}
```

This will nicely print the the correct i (3 and 4) but the dimensions of all_perm remain with 3 columns instead of 4. The number of rows does change.

If I run the two (3 and 4) directly it does work, i.e. replacing the #THE FOR LOOP THAT DOESN'T WORK part to:

```
all_perm <- merge(all_perm, as.data.frame(kCounts[,3]),all=TRUE)
all_perm <- all_perm[rowSums(all_perm) <= n,]
all_perm <- merge(all_perm, as.data.frame(kCounts[,4]),all=TRUE)
all_perm <- all_perm[rowSums(all_perm) <= n,]
dim(all_perm)
```

It correctly shows that all_perm now has 4 columns.

I really don't get why the for loop doesn't work. I tried also a while loop but also that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

**Purpose**:
This code is part of function I'm trying to make for myself, where I'm trying to perform a multinomial test. It's just for a theoretical exercise to understand how the test works. The easy way to perform a multinomial test is by either using the EMT library and the 'multinomial.test' function, or xnomial library and the 'xmulti' function.

Comment: Your loop tries to merge a yet inexistent object `all_perm` (see error message) whereas your manual attempt creates this object from `kCounts`. Aside: in R, a loop is often better replaced with some variant of `apply` or `Map` (base or {purrr}). Particularly when "grow"ing objects e.g. by adding columns, your code can become unnecessarily slow. Loops, in R, are a tempting construct to grow things.

Comment: thanks, indeed created the example too quickly. If I create the all_perm before the loop it will update it for the first in the loop (3) but not with (4). I'm quite puzzled why not. Have adapted the code in the OP.

Comment: If you `print(all_perm)` inside your loop, you'll see that its columns have names `kCounts[, i]`, `x` and `kCounts[, 2]`, which should tell you what is going wrong.  However, as @I_O has already mentioned, your approach is far from optimal (if you're writing R code and thinking of using a `for` loop), there's almost certainly a better way to do it).  So please edit your question to indicate the *purpose* of your code (and give us your expected output) and you will receive answers that will both solve your problem *and* improve the efficiency of your code.

Comment: Thanks. The column names were indeed left a bit meaningless. I've added a 'purpose' part in my OP. The all_perm is used later on and the column names are not really further needed. 
I understand the for loop is far from optimal, but makes the code somewhat easier to read for myself and understand what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wanted a dataframe of *k* columns, where each row is a unique *n*-element sample (with replacement) of the numbers `0:n` and the `rowSum` does not exceed *n*, here's one "loopless" approach:

1. get the combinations and `t`ranspose the resulting k × n matrix to n × k:

```
all_perms <- t(combn(rep(0:n, times = k), k))
```

```
> all_perms |> head(3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    2    3
[2,]    0    1    2    4
[3,]    0    1    2    5

> nrow(all_perms)
[1] 1581580
```

2. keep only rows with row sums <= *n*

```
all_perms <- 
  subset(all_perms,
         rowSums(all_perms) <= n
         )
```

```
> nrow(all_perms)
[1] 81769
```

3. if needed, convert to dataframe and sort (*V1* changing fastest):

```
library(dplyr) ## for convenient multi-column sort

all_perms <- 
  all_perms |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  arrange(V4, V3, V2, V1)
```

```
> all_perms |> head(3)
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  0  0  0  0
2  1  0  0  0
3  2  0  0  0
```

Comment: thanks for this solution. The column names seem to be the main cause. 

I've also asked the question on the R community forum. A user 'technocrat' explained that the all_perms is stored globally but in the loop locally, causing the issue.
Also a user 'nirgrahamuk' gave a solution using still the for-loop but changing it so the column names change. This solution is most likely less optimized than yours.  The thread on the R community is [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/for-loop-not-updating-variable/156907/2).